# Video.js event listener not working in safari and chrome

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, video.js

I am using `video.js` to play HTML5 video and I have added the event listener for detecting when the video will be ended. When the video ends I am trying to play next video. It's working fine with other browsers except Chrome and Safari. In both of them the first video is getting played, but the second video isn't.
Below is my code:

```xml
<video id="home_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" 
  controls preload="none" width="640" height="264">
  <source src="latest.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
  <source src="latest.ogv" type='video/ogg'/>
</video>
<script>
  var homePlayer = _V_("home_video");
  var myFunc = function () {
    var myPlayer = _V_("home_video");
    // Do something when the event is fired
    alert("hi");
    myPlayer.src([
      { type: "video/mp4", src: "latest1.mp4" }, 
      { type: video/ogg", src: "latest1.ogv" }]);
    myPlayer.play();
  };
  homePlayer.addEvent("ended", myFunc);
</script>
```

Note: I get the alert in all the browsers but the second video is not being played in Safari and Chrome.

Comment: Did you mean to have a quote before `video/ogg`?

Comment: yes i do have quote before video/ogg in my code